# Repeat length of list on Python?

Tags: python, list, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [find the maximum number in a list using a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448692/find-the-maximum-number-in-a-list-using-a-loop)

I'm finding the maximum number in a list on Python by using a loop. In order to do that, I need to have a loop where it goes through the entire list. What loop can I use that runs through the entire list? I'm new to Python.

Comment: I would be obliged to help, if I only understood your question. Could you rephrase it a bit?

Comment: Check out the python [documentation](http://python.org/doc/). Most likely the answer that you seek is there.

Comment: from an earlier comment: [whatcha talkin bout willis?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qw9oX-kZ_9k)

Comment: What was wrong with the (highly upvoted) answers to [the exact same question you asked 30 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448692/find-the-maximum-number-in-a-list-using-a-loop)?

Comment: You want to use a `for` loop. Python docs: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: If your struggling with understanding how a for loop works, check out this khan academy video on youtube. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LgyKiq_hU0

Answer (score 1):

You can go through a list with a for loop like:

```
for item in lst:
    # do something with item
```

However, an easier way to get the maximum item in a list (which appears to be what you want) is:

```
max(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeating a block of code n times, where n is the length of some_list is done like this:

```
for i in xrange(len(some_list)):
    # block of code
```

or...

```
i = 0
while i < len(some_list):
    # block of code
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
max = None
for e in lst:
    if max is None or e > max: max = e
```

But as David already stated, simply calling `max(lst)` would do the job.

Comment: Don't call your variable `max` though

Comment: Also note this will break for python 3, where you can't compare NoneType and, say, int.