# the use of combining max, xrange and lambda function in python

Tags: python, lambda, max, xrange, matrix-decomposition

I have found a code that pivotize a square matrix for LU decomposition, but I can't understand some of them.

```
def pivotize(m):
    """Creates the pivoting matrix for m."""
    n = len(m)
    ID = [[float(i == j) for i in xrange(n)] for j in xrange(n)]
    for j in xrange(n):
        row = max(xrange(j, n), key=lambda i: abs(m[i][j]))
        if j != row:
            ID[j], ID[row] = ID[row], ID[j]
    return ID
```

First, isn't the line for ID simply the identity matrix? any advantage doing this?

Second, I can't really understand the line for row. I know lambda is used to define a function in the text, and it simply returns the value of M_ij once the value of i is supplied (and the value of j depends on the for loop), but what is i?

And isn't xrange similar to range? But what does it return here?

And when combined with the function max, what happens? I just don't know what are the things inside the max function that are being compared.

Sorry if this question sounds stupid. I'm pretty new to programming

Comment: `i` comes from `xrange(j, n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, isn't the line for ID simply the identity matrix?

Yes.

> Second, I can't really understand the line for row....

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296755/python-max-function-using-key-and-lambda-expression) for a discussion about the max/key/lambda interaction.  To answer "what is `i`?", its the argument to the lambda function, `i` could equivalently be `x` for `foo`.  (For clarity, yielding `abs(m[x][j])` and `abs(m[foo][j])`, respectively).

> And isn't xrange similar to range?

Yes.  In Python 2 `xrange` returns a sequence object that lazily computes the next value, only when needed.  [See this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange-functions-in-python-2-x).  When looped through in entirety, `range` and `xrange` will produce the same results, with different implementations.

> But what does it return here?

Line 5's `xrange(n)` will return the integer values from 0 to (n-1) while Line 6's `xrange(j, n)` will return the integer values from j to (n-1).

**EDIT**

More on lambda:

Consider how you might take a given sequence of numbers, and double each of them.  First define a function that doubles a number `x` and returns that value.  Then map that function to each element of a sequence.

```
# Traditional
def double(x): return x*2
print map(double, [1,2,3,4])         # [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

You could have alternatively used an anonymous (lambda) function to do the same thing:

```
# Lambda
print map(lambda i: i*2, [1,2,3,4])  # [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Note that everything is the same, except the definition of the `double` function is gone and the reference to the function in the call to `map` is replaced by the "inline" lambda function.

**EDIT 2**

> And when combined with the function max, what happens?

This line `row = max(xrange(j, n), key=lambda i: abs(m[i][j]))` can be broken down as follows:

- `xrange(j,n)` generates a sequence of integers from `j` (inclusive) to `n` (exclusive).
- Each of those integers are then "passed" as arguments to the function in the key argument.  In other words, they're each used as the `i` in the lambda function.  The lambda function "returns" the absolute value of the `i`th row and `j`th column.[1]
- The `max` function then finds the greatest value of these "lambda outputs" and sets `row` equal to it.

This could have alternatively been written as a max of a list comprehension:

```
row = max( [abs(m[i][j]) for i in xrange(j,n)] )
```

Or as [Dan D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388787/dan-d) points out in his comment, written as a generator expression (without creating an intermediary list) as simply:

```
row = max( abs(m[i][j]) for i in xrange(j,n) )
```

Notes:

[1] Some assumptions here, but row-column is a standard way of expressing matrices.

Comment: I know 'i' is the argument to the lambda function, but 'where' is i? Normally after I define a function (say y=np.sin(t)), I will declare t=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi) as the arguments, but now I'm just confused as there aren't any other codes related to i...

Comment: re: your comment edit -- `i` is no more made up than `x` is in the definition of the `double` function: `double(x):`

Comment: @Physicist: `i` is just an arbitray name given to the argument that gets passed to the `key` function whose return value determines the ordering used by the `max()` function. In this context it will be an integer with a value from `j` to `n-1` inclusive because of the `xrange(j, n)`.

Comment: Note that as `max` can take any iterable, even a generator expression, you can write `row = max( abs(m[i][j]) for i in xrange(j,n) )` and save creating an actual `list` due to the list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

`xrange` is an Python2 construct that's used for handling `range` memory efficient. Before`range` actually created a list, and then `for` loop would run through it. `xrange` however is a generator, that means it spits out 1 value at a time when it's asked to, without creating a full list.

`ID` is actually an identity matrix. You're right there. That's a neat trick that boolean can be converted to float of value `1.0`.

Then the snippet runs through all the remaining rows and finds the maximum value of that row in the original matrix `row = max(xrange(j, n), key=lambda i: abs(m[i][j]))`. Notice that there's a 2nd nice trick in there, `max` can take any iterable object to operate on, including generators. `lambda` keyword in that row indicates what's known as "anonymous function".

In more details: Anonymous functions are functions that are not bound to an identifier. Lambda function in your snippet takes in 1 value, `i` and returns an absolute value at matrix position `m[i][j]`. The values that get sent as the input for the function are provided by the generator `xrange(j, n)`.

`max` then takes the return values of the lambda function as the thing it actually compares. In example, in python3 it's not possible to compare 2 different types. I.e. comparing string > int produces: `TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()`. However if we're sure that the list contains numbers, just in different format, you can do something like:

```
>>> l = ["1", "2", 3, 4]
>>> max(l, key=lambda x: int(x))
4
>>> min(l, key=lambda x: int(x))
'1' #type 'str'
```

This just shows, that the actual compared values are the returns of your `key` function, but actual produced values are your original input values.

Once it found the rows maximum value, it "rotates", by substitution `ID[j], ID[row] = ID[row], ID[j]`, all the other rows, **in the identity matrix**, around it so that only the maximum value remains on the diagonal.

This helps prevent division by a too small a number in the next step of LU decomposition.

What you get in return, isn't the original matrix, rotated, but a matrix of `1.0`s and `0.0`s that is your transformation matrix that multiplied by the original one will result in the pivoted matrix.

This seems a very nicely written function that saves memory and helps performance in python. Hopefully I did this right.