# max value of a list filled with named tuples

Tags: python, max, namedtuple

I create a list filled with named tuples:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Point', 'x y')
a = Point(5,4)
b = Point(8,3)
tab = [a,b]

print tab
>>[Point(x=5, y=4), Point(x=8, y=3)]
```

I would like to have the max of the x values in the list 'tab'

```
max(tab.x)
>> 8
```

Comment: `print max([i.x for i in tab])`

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296755/python-max-function-using-key-and-lambda-expression) for another approach

Answer (score 5):

Try like this,

```
>>> max(tab, key=lambda k: k.x)
Point(x=8, y=3)
>>> max(tab, key=lambda k: k.x).x
8
```

> The optional key argument specifies a one-argument ordering function
>   like that used for list.sort(). The key argument, if supplied, must be
>   in keyword form (for example, max(a,b,c,key=func)).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you explain me this code please ? : key=lambda k: k.x

Comment: `lambda k: k.x` returns sorting key

Comment: Or `key=operator.attrgetter('x')`.

Answer (score 2):

You may simple do it as :

```
print max([i.x for i in tab])
```

However it may not be the best approach to do the same.