# How to return values in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def consensus(seqs):    
>>> profiel(seqs)
    {'A': [0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 3], 'C': [0, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 5, 1], 'T': [3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1], 'G': [4, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2]}
>>> consensus(profiel(seqs))
    'GCCNTACA'
```

How can I return the key of the dictionary when it have the highest number in the list? So the first one is a `G` because

`A = 0 , C = 0, T = 3, G = 4`

And so on.

Comment: What happens if more than one have the highest number?

Comment: Any attempts from your side?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Well I can find the highest with 'max()' , but i can't return the key.

Comment: Does anyone actually took a look to the dict? the highest number is a 5 and is in C...

Comment: I explain it in my question. In your case  A = 0, C = 5, T = 1, G = 1. Thats why the second last is a 'C'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use the `key` keyword of the max function ([python max function using 'key' and lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296755/python-max-function-using-key-and-lambda-expression)). Then, you can use a generator expression to iterate through the lists and join it into a string.

```
dic = {'A': [0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 3], 'C': [0, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 5, 1], 'T': [3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1], 'G': [4, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2]}
''.join(max(dic, key=lambda v: dic[v][i]) for i in xrange(len(dic['A'])))
### 'GCCATACA'
```

Note that this only works if all lists have the same number of elements.

Comment: same comment as other answer, there is a 5 in C how can the biggest be G?

Comment: @DanielSanchez I think you might have misunderstood the question ... as far as I can tell, the op is not looking for the key with the highest number but a list of keys. At each index i of that list, the key k is the one for which dic[k][i] is maximal. ... I think

Comment: Yep, was talking with Borja about what he actually wants, i downvoted the question for that.

Comment: @Victor does my code give you what you need or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I think so but is xrange() the same as range()? Because my python doesn't know what xrange() is.

Comment: @Victor that depends what version of python you are using ... in python 2.7, xrange is the generator version of range ... in any case, you can replace it by range. however, in python 2.7, xrange is usually preferable since you do not put the entire list in memory but just one item at a time.

Answer (score 0):

To select key with max value, use this

```
max(dict, key=dict.get)
```

***Example:***

```
item = d[d.keys()[0]]

''.join(
    max(d, key=lambda key: d.get(key)[i]) for i in range(len(item))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job, key of the list with the highest value on it:

```
mydict = {'A': [0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 3], 'C': [0, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 5, 1], 'T': [3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1], 'G': [4, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2]}

def getKeyBigger(d);
    key,_ = reduce(lambda x, y: x if max(x[1]) > max(y[1]) else y, d.items())
    return key

>>>print getKeyBigger(mydict)
>>>C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def return_max(dic): 
    maxnum = max(i[0] for i in dic.values())        
    for i in dic.iteritems():
        if maxnum == i[1][0]:
            return i[0]

dic = {'A': [0, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 3], 'C': [0, 4, 3, 1, 0, 0, 5, 1], 'T': [3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1], 'G': [4, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2]}
print return_max(dic)
```

Output:

```
G
```

Comment: He is looking for the biggest *first number*.

Comment: i did not understood that, so my bad then :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on zetsys solution, here's a (ugly) one liner:

```
"".join([max(d, key={k: v[x] for k, v in d.items()}.get) for x in xrange(len(d.values()[0]))]
```

It makes the assumption that every list has the same length.
(and d is your input dictionary)