# What is the lambda function doing in this code?

Tags: python, lambda

I have the following code for a greedy implementation of the traveling salesman problem.  I can't wrap my head around what exactly the lambda function does in this code.

```
def distance(p1, p2):
    return ((p1[0] - p2[0])**2 + (p1[1] - p2[1])**2) ** 0.5

def tsp_greedy(points, start=None):
    if start is None:
        start = points[0]
    to_visit = points
    path = [start]
    to_visit.remove(start)
    while to_visit:
        closest = min(to_visit, key=lambda x: distance(path[-1], x))
        path.append(closest)
        to_visit.remove(closest)
    return path
```

I realize it's creating an anonymous function which x gets passed into.  But I'm not sure what is getting passed into this function.  What is x?

Comment: x is each value in `to_visit` iterable. `min()` computes `key` value for each value, returns value where `key` function has lowest value.

Comment: Does this answer solve your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18296814/406423

Comment: It is iterating through all the items in path, passing the current item being visited as x and comparing to the next in path (as path[-1])
as to get the min distance.

Comment: @MadMike good find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest` becomes `to_visit[i]` such that

```
distance(path[-1], to_visit[i]) = 
  min(distance(path[-1], to_visit[0]), distance(path[-1], to_visit[1]), ...)
```

In other words, the lambda function makes comparison not by `to_visit[i]` but by `distance(path[-1], to_visit[i])`.

Comment: `min` returns the `x` element from `to_visit` having the lowest `distance(path[-1], x)`, not the distance itself

Comment: Yes, you are right.