# find tuple with min sum in a python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

In a list of python tuple, I need to find the tuple with min sum.

for example,

```
a = [ (2, 6) , (1,3) , (0,2) ]
```

`(0, 2)` should be returned because its sum is minimal.

I know how to do it by list comprehension and then find the smallest tuple sum.

```
 minTuple = min([((x[0] + x[1]), (x[0], x[1])) for x in a ], key = lambda x : x[0] )
```

I would like to do it by map/lambda and list comprehension.

How to implement it efficiently?

Comment: How do you handle ties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer to your question is just to use the `min()` function, provided with a key to the array. The `key` parameter specifies a set of rules for comparison that `min()` uses to evaluate the tuples.

See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296755/python-max-function-using-key-and-lambda-expression).

`min(a, key=sum)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
>>> a = [ (2, 6) , (1,3) , (0,2) ]
>>> min(a, key=sum)
(0, 2)

>>> a = [ (2, 6) , (1,3) , (0,7) ]
>>> min(a, key=sum)
(1, 3)
```