# How to return max of objects's sequence, where each objects have same fields with different values?

Tags: python, oop, sequence

Suppose, we have sequence of instances of one class. 
Let's describe class

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, lastname):
        self.name = name
        self.lastname = lastname
```

Creating instances:

```
obj1 = Person('Andrew', 'Martin')
obj2 = Person('Mark', 'Levy')
obj3 = Person('Harry', 'Anderson')
objs = (obj1, obj2, obj3)
```

I want to return the maximum from the tuple in two fields. Something like the following:

```
from operator import attrgetter
max_obj = max(objs, key=(attrgetter('lastname'), attrgetter('name')))
```

Such code raise an error

> (TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable).

How, then, can one get the maximum?

Comment: elaborate your "maximum"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate these properties in the key using a lambda function:

```
max_obj = max(objs, key=lambda x: x.lastname.lower() + x.name.lower())
```

For instance:

```
obj1 = Person('George', 'Martin')
obj2 = Person('Beth', 'Martin')
obj3 = Person('Mark', 'Levy')
obj4 = Person('Harry', 'Anderson')
objs = (obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4)

from operator import attrgetter
max_obj = max(objs, key=lambda x: x.lastname.lower() + x.name.lower())
print(max_obj.name)

Out: George
```

More on using functions as keys for the `max` function can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18296814/1947677).