# How can I return the highest score from a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I must create a function that receives by parameter the 4 students (dictionaries) and returns the student with the highest average.

```
def create_student(nom: str, cod: str, gen: str, carr: str, media: float, ssc: float) -> dict:
    dic_student = {"name": nom,
                   "code": cod,
                   "sex": gen,
                   "career": carr,
                   "media": media,
                   "ssc": ssc}
    return dic_student

# Main program
student1 = create_student("Juan Pérez", "201824736", "male", "Biology", 3.78, 0.7)
student2 = create_student("Ana Gavalda", "201724736", "female", "political science", 4.25, 3.5)
student3 = create_student("Bastien Bosa", "201815217", "male", "Economy", 3.21, 2.3)
student4 = create_student("Catalina Gómez", "201715400", "female", "Art", 3.8, 4)

print("The students are:\n", "student 1:\n", student1,
  "\nstudent 2:\n", student2,
  "\nstudent 3:\n", student3,
  "\nstudent4:\n", student4)
```

Comment: What have you tried to find the maximum amongst some objects?

Comment: I have tried to create a function with if else (coditions) but I don't really think thats the best way.

Comment: What would you do to find the maximum value of a list of ints?

Comment: Python's max function allows a key function see [python max function using 'key' and lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296755/python-max-function-using-key-and-lambda-expression) which is useful for selecting the max between multiple objects.

Comment: So if I right understand you question, Do you need to sort students by media and ssc values?

Comment: yes, but only with media not ssc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For clarity I left out things like parameter checking, but the basic idea is: sort the students by `media` then return the student with the highest value.

Example:

```
def find_top_student(*students):
    sorted_students = sorted(students, key=lambda s: s["media"], reverse=True)
    return sorted_students[0]

top_student = find_top_student(student1, student2, student3, student4)

print(top_student["name"])
```

Output:

```
Ana Gavalda
```

Comment: you are the best, thank you too much :)