# Max values in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, max

I have a list of lists and I need to find the maximum value of each list, but I don't know how to do it.

```
l = [['6', '6', '11', '12', '10', '6', '9', '10', '6'], ['4'], ['6', '20', '10', '6', '10', '7', '8'], ['8', '4', '1', '5', '5']]
```

The maximum values ​​have to come back in a list, because then I'll have to sum them.
Example:

```
max_values = [12, 4, 20, 8]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a simple list comprehension with `max` to get the biggest value and `map` to convert all elements to `int`:

```py
max_values = [max(map(int, i)) for i in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using lamda and the max built-in function in combination, or `map` the list and use `max` afterwords:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18296814/13526701 Or
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70155571/13526701