# Getting attributte value from object where other value in this object is the biggest

Tags: python, object, max

I have this list of objects which have p1, and p2 parameter (and some other stuff).

```
Job("J1", p1=8, p2=3)
Job("J2", p1=7, p2=11)
Job("J3", p1=5, p2=12)
Job("J4", p1=10, p2=5)
...
Job("J222",p1=22,p2=3)
```

With python, I can easily get max value of p2 by

```
(max(job.p2 for job in instance.jobs))
```

but how do I get the value of p1, where p2 is the biggest?

Seems simple, but I can't get it anyway... Could You guys help me?

Comment: You should look at answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296755/python-max-function-using-key-and-lambda-expression).

Comment: Did something like this, but I think it makes no sense and adds to much job (but it works...)
```for job in instance.jobs:
        maxp1=(max(job.p2 for job in schedule.instance.jobs))
        if job.p2 == maxp1:
            print(job.p1)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop like this:

```
mx = -inf

for job in instance.jobs:
    if job.p2 > mx:
        mx = job.p2
        var = job
print(mx)
print(var)
print(var.p1)
```

Example output:

```
12
<object>
5
```

Comment: Oh, so this is that simple... damn Thanks a lot, it works, and I think i understand it :D

Answer (score 0):

If `instance.jobs` is the iterable you want to check and all elements have a `p1` and a `p2` attribute, use

```
max(instance.jobs, key=lambda job: job.p2).p1
```

If there are multiple jobs where `p2` is largest, you will get an arbitrary `p1` value from one of those jobs.

Comment: This also works... Python is a great thing, thanks a lot! Gotta get used&learn how to use lambda functions