# Python: get value from row and column from a matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, matrix

I'm learning how to code and I didn't quite understand how a class really works. If I create a matrix for example:

```
class Matrix(object):

 def __init__(self,i,j,value):
  self.rows = i
  self.cols = j
  self.value = value
```

if I have a random matrix and want to select the biggest value in a row, i can write:

```
for value in row
```

and the program will know I mean the value ij in the ith row?

Comment: If you are struggling with python classes, check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python And this one talks a bit about matrices http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python Udacity also have some good starting courses on python.

Comment: Is self.rows a list of rows (i.e. self.rows = ['dog','cat',hamster']), or is it an integer indicating the number of rows in your Matrix?

Comment: check this out: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in python Matrixes would be two dimensional arrays. Like:

```
matrix = [[11,12,13,14],[21,22,23,24],[31,32,33,34]]
```

//is the same as

would give you a matrix like:

```
11 12 13 14 
21 22 23 24
31 32 33 34
```

so you have an array which stores the rows (the outer array) and one array for each row. To access e.g. the value at position (2,4) which is `24` you would do

```
matrix[1][3]
```

as `matrix[1] = [21,22,23,24]` and `matrix[1][3] = [21,22,23,24][3] = 24`

To iterate over your matrix (i.e. your two dimensional array) you can do:

```
#iterate over the rows
for row in matrix:
    #max value
    max = max(row)
    print max
    #if you want to iterate over the elements in the row do:
    for element in row:
        print element
```

In Your example you are defining a Matrix class which will be initialized with 3 parameters: `i`, `j` and `value`. You are not doing more. For examples of your own matrix class you could have a look [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578131-a-simple-matrix-class/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to interpolate indexes:

```
>>> for i, j in enumerate(["a","b","c"]):
...   print i, j
... 
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

In your case:

```
# suppose m is an instance of class Matrix
for i, row in enumerate(m.value):
    for j, ele in enumerate(row):
        # find greatest and halt
        # i, j are the expected index
        yeild i, j
```

To find a largest element from a list there are multiple ways, for example: [Pythonic way to find maximum value and its index in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193498/pythonic-way-to-find-maximum-value-and-its-index-in-a-list)

However, more clever way is to utilize [numpy.matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) if programming yourself is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
for value in row
```

code will NOT get you the biggest value in the row. It will just iterate (run through) each item in the row (once you define row of course). You need to add a check to get the biggest number.