# Return the index of the maximum element in a list

Tags: python, list, indexing, max

I have calculated the histogram of different pixels using the following statement:

```
pixel_histogram = [float(x)/float(number_of_pixels) for x in pixel_frequency]
```

If I want to return the maximum element in the list, I would simply do the following:

```
max(pixel_histogram)
```

How can I return the index of this maximum element?

Thanks.

Comment: try `np.argmax()` or `pixel_histogram.index(max(pixel_histogram))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to find maximum value and its index in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193498/pythonic-way-to-find-maximum-value-and-its-index-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
max_index, max_value = max(enumerate(pixel_histogram), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

**Example:**

```
>>> l = [1, 3, 6, 2, 3, 5]
>>> max_index, max_value = max(enumerate(l), key=lambda item: item[1])
>>> max_value
6
>>> max_index
2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first occurence of the maximum element in the list, you can use

```
pixel_histogram.index(max(pixel_istogram))
```

oherwise, you should specify the parameters that you want to consider for choosing which "max" is correct