# Python - Get largest number from a list of numbers in a file

Tags: python, list, ipython

I apologize but I searched and could not find an existing question/answer that solved this.

Simply put, I just need to take a list of numbers in a file and grab the largest number.I would typically use bash but i have a Python requirement.

I know how to open a file for reading and output the contents of the file but I can't get it to process the for loop output. Thank you in advance.

Here's the bash equivalent of what i need to do in python:

```
chrisk@kihei:~$ cat foo
214101721792
214101675361
214101684152
214101743134
214101718688
214101731297
214101715541
214101743273
214101722035
214101703116
214101696928
214101687776
chrisk@kihei:~$ sort foo | tail -1
214101743273
chrisk@kihei:~$
```

Comment: Search for "python read file" and "python get max number"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to find maximum value and its index in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193498/pythonic-way-to-find-maximum-value-and-its-index-in-a-list)

Comment: Thank you.. getting this for some reason..Interpreter is Python 2.7.12 >>> sorted(map(int, open('foo')))[-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'd2Z5O3e215JM130F\n'

Comment: @user1117603, the file you provided in the question did not include any non-numeric lines. Those cannot be converted to integers simply by bassing them to `int`. Perhaps you could show us a larger portion of your actual input data, so we may help you.

Comment: @bla yeah there's a line feed character after each value '\n' and that's why it doesn't think it's an int. Trying to figure out how to strip it... any pointers would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I got it.. thank you for your help: int(sorted(map(int, open('foo')))[-1])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('foo') as f:
    max_num = max(int(i) for i in f)

print(max_num)
```