# Printing out the nth value of the max number within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, max

I want to print out the nth value of the the maximum number within a list

```
list_= [1,3,2,2,8,11,4]
max_val = max(list_)
```

Expected output

```
The maximum value of 11 is at the 6th place from the start of the order
```

Comment: See the `index` method.

Comment: `list_.index(max(list_))` index => `list_.index(max(list_)) + 1`th place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to find maximum value and its index in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193498/pythonic-way-to-find-maximum-value-and-its-index-in-a-list)

Comment: `index` unnecessarily loops through the list twice. Refer to the answers on the linked post for faster answers.

Comment: @Aplet123 @Escualo's answer in the given link seems to suggest the explicit usage of `index` is just as fast if not faster.

Answer (score 0):

Take index of max value in the list

```
list_.index(max(list_))
```