# How to find the index of the max value in a list for Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, element

I have a list, and I need to find the maximum element in the list and also record the index at which that max element is at.

This is my code.

```
list_c = [-14, 7, -9, 2]

max_val = 0
idx_max = 0

for i in range(len(list_c)):
    if list_c[i] > max_val:
        max_val = list_c[i]
        idx_max = list_c.index(i)

return list_c, max_val, idx_max
```

Please help. I am just beginning to code and got stuck here.

Comment: Use this ```idx_max = list_c.index(list_c[i])```. You are trying to find the index of ```i```. It should be ```list_c[i]```,

Comment: Untested: `max(enumerate(list_c), key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: Please explain what you expect as an output and what you receive instead. And what do you hope to do with this line: `idx_max = list_c.index(i)`?

Comment: @Ram: If you want to assign the value of `i` to `idx_max` then `idx_max = list_c.index(list_c[i])` is a strange way to do it. A simple `idx_max = i` is enough.

Comment: @Matthias Yeah. True!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to find maximum value and its index in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193498/pythonic-way-to-find-maximum-value-and-its-index-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are trying to find the index of `i`. It should be `list_c[i]`.

> Easy way/Better way is: `idx_max = i`. (Based on @Matthias comment above.)

- Use `print` to print the results and not `return`. You use `return` inside functions.
- Also your code doesn't work if `list_c` has all negative values because you are setting `max_val` to `0`. You get a 0 always.

```
list_c = [-14, 7, -9, 2]

max_val = 0
idx_max = 0

for i in range(len(list_c)):
    if list_c[i] > max_val:
        max_val = list_c[i]
        idx_max = i

print(list_c, max_val, idx_max)
```

```
[-14, 7, -9, 2] 7 1
```

Answer (score 6):

It is easiest to just apply logic to the entire list. You can get the max value of a list using max(list), and you can use the same index function you use above to get the index of this number in the list.

```
max_val = max(list_c)
idx_max = list_c.index(max_val)
```

If you want to loop over the values to find the max, then take note of the following:

1. list.index(value) will find the index of that value in the list. In your case you are writing list.index(index_number) which doesnt make sense. 'i' already represents the list index, so just set idx_max = 'i'.
2. Further, you should note that if you set max_val to zero, if all the list items are less than zero, it will stay at zero during the loop and never find the max value. It is better to start by setting max_val to the first item of the list ie list_c[0].

   ```
    list_c = [-14, 7, -9, 2]

    max_val = list_c[0]
    idx_max = 0

    for i in range(len(list_c)):
        if list_c[i] > max_val:
            max_val = list_c[i]
            idx_max = i
   ```

NB 'return' is used to return values from a function. If you want to print the values, use print(list_c, max_val, idx_max).

Answer (score 2):

Looping twice through an array is inefficient. Use built-in **enumerate()** and **max()** with the comparison lambda expression returning the second element  of the enumeration:

```
>>> list_c = [-14, 7, -9, 2]
>>> print(max(enumerate(list_c), key=lambda x: x[1]))
(1, 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NumPy argmax() by converting your list to a NumPy array.

```
import numpy as np
list_c = [-14, 7, -9, 2]
print("Index max:",np.argmax(np.asarray(list_c)))
print("Value max:",list_c[np.argmax(np.asarray(list_c))])
```

Index max: 1

Value max: 7

Answer (score 0):

`.index` can only be done on elements in the list. So, do `idx_max = list_c.index(list_c[i])`

```
max_val = list_c[i]
idx_max = list_c.index(list_c[i])
```

However, here is a shortened version

```
list_c = [-14, 7, -9, 2]
print(max(list_c),list_c.index(max(list_c)))
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need is .max() and .index() function. First, you find max element of the list, then just simply get it index using index() function.

You can see a complete tutorial here: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-find-the-index-of-the-max-value-in-a-list-in-python

Comment: Please provide the code and some description about your code!

Comment: Here on Stack Overflow we would like to create a database of solutions. Link-only answers are not helpful on that since links can and will die.